# Android UI test for Compose HorizontalPager scrollToPage

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose, ui-automation, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I'm using HorizontalPager which shows a Skip option to scroll to last page.

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

ConstraintView {

    val (skipText, pager) = createRefs()

    ....
    
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.skip),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(skipText) {
                        ....
                    }
                    .clickable {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            pagerState.scrollToPage(page = pageCount - 1)
                        }
                    }
            )
    ....
}
```

As this is working as expected, I'm writing composeTest for this use case.

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

@Before
fun setup() {
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        content()
    }
}

@Test
fun testOnClickSkipNavigateToLastPageInNodeTree() = {
    composeTestRule.apply {
        onNodeWithText("First Page").assertIsDisplayed() // Text displayed in first page
        onNodeWithText("Skip").assertIsDisplayed()
        onNodeWithText("Skip").performClick()
        
        onRoot(useUnmergedTree = true).printToLog("TAG") // Printing the nodes
        
        onNodeWithText("Last Page").assertIsDisplayed() // Text displayed in last page
```

But the above code fails with error,

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed to perform isDisplayed check.
Reason: Expected exactly '1' node but could not find any node that satisfies: (Text + EditableText contains 'Last Page' (ignoreCase: false))
```

I assume this is because of the `coroutineScope`. I tried few options that I'm aware of such as `waitUntil`, `waitUntilExists` and even `Thread.sleep` on Skip text. But still it fails. I doubt the `Coroutines` and unable to find how to resolve this.

Printing the nodes results,

```
Node #1 at (l=0.0, t=279.0, r=1080.0, b=2141.0)px
|-Node #2 at (l=0.0, t=279.0, r=1080.0, b=2141.0)px
    DesignInfoProvider = 'androidx.constraintlayout.compose.Measurer@96f3373'
        |-Node #4 at (l=909.0, t=279.0, r=1080.0, b=419.0)px
        | Focused = 'false'
        | Text = '[Skip]'
        | Actions = [OnClick, RequestFocus, GetTextLayoutResult]
        | MergeDescendants = 'true'
        |-Node #5 at (l=0.0, t=349.0, r=1080.0, b=2211.0)px
            HorizontalScrollAxisRange = 'ScrollAxisRange(value=0.0, maxValue=4.0, reverseScrolling=false)'
            CollectionInfo = 'androidx.compose.ui.semantics.CollectionInfo@3f82230'
            Actions = [IndexForKey, ScrollBy, ScrollToIndex]
                    |-Node #12 at (l=225.0, t=1069.0, r=856.0, b=1209.0)px
                    | Text = ‘[First Page]’
                    | Actions = [GetTextLayoutResult]
```

As one can see it prints `First Page` but I expect it to print `Last Page`. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

**UPDATE:** This test passes in pixel emulator but fails in pixel device